# VMware Player 12 option "guest isolation" missing

Tags: vmware, isolation

I have a host (Windows 10) running VMware Player 12.5.4. I created a VM Guest (Windows 7) and also installed the VMware Tools on that. However the option "guest isolation" is not showing up in the VM preferences. Drag and Drop works but I want to disable that feature. Reinstalling the VMware Tools didn't help.

Could it be that "guest isolation" is a Pro feature only? Or did it get removed completely out of the product?

Answer (score 15):

I add these to my *.vmx files to get to the bios and enable copy-paste:

```
isolation.tools.copy.disable = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.paste.disable = "FALSE"
bios.bootDelay = "2000"
```

You can try changing FALSE to TRUE and see if that disables copy-paste.